# Why doesn't a part of this tkinter Menu widget not show up?

Tags: python, macos, menu, tkinter

I am creating a Text editor and I am trying to edit the default Mac Application menu.[image: Mac application menu]
<—The Menu

I followed [this](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/menus.html) tutorial to edit it and it works fine on its own like this:

```
from Tkinter import *
root=Tk()
menubar = Menu(root)
appmenu = Menu(menubar, name='apple')
menubar.add_cascade(menu=appmenu)
appmenu.add_command(label='About My Application')
appmenu.add_separator()
root['menu'] = menubar
root.mainloop()
```

But when I try add in my menubar items for my text editor in another script, it will only display the text editor bits and not the edited application menu.

> **How can I get both to show at the same time?**

*Problem code:*

```
from Tkinter import *
class Main(object):
    def __init__(self, root):
        root.title("PyText")
        #Text editor menu items
        self.m1=Menu(root)

        self.fm=Menu(self.m1, tearoff=0)
        self.fm.add_command(label="New", command=self.saveas)
        self.fm.add_command(label="Open", command=self.saveas)
        self.fm.add_command(label="Save", command=self.saveas)
        self.fm.add_command(label="Save as...", command=self.saveas)
        self.fm.add_command(label="Close", command=self.saveas)
        self.fm.add_separator()
        self.fm.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)
        self.m1.add_cascade(label="File", menu=self.fm)

        self.editmenu = Menu(self.m1, tearoff=0)
        self.editmenu.add_command(label="Undo", command=self.saveas)
        self.editmenu.add_separator()
        self.editmenu.add_command(label="Cut", command=self.saveas)
        self.editmenu.add_command(label="Copy", command=self.saveas)
        self.editmenu.add_command(label="Paste", command=self.saveas)
        self.editmenu.add_command(label="Delete", command=self.saveas)
        self.editmenu.add_command(label="Select All", command=self.saveas)
        self.editmenu.add_separator()
        self.m1.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=self.editmenu)
        #Problem code here
        self.appmenu = Menu(self.m1, name="apple", tearoff=0)
        self.m1.add_cascade(menu=self.appmenu)
        self.appmenu.add_command(label="About PyText")
        self.appmenu.add_separator()

        root.config(menu=self.m1)



        self.t1=Text(root)
        self.t1.config(width=90, height=40)
        self.t1.grid()

    def saveas(self):
        self.filewin = Toplevel()
        self.filewin.title("Name")
        self.e1=Entry(self.filewin)
        self.e1.grid()
        self.button = Button(self.filewin, text="Save", command=self.save)
        self.button.grid()

    def save(self):
        with open(self.e1.get(), "w") as f: # this instance variable can be accessed
            f.write(self.t1.get('1.0', 'end'))


root = Tk()
app = Main(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The bit from the tutorial doesn't work fine for me, instead of displaying `apple` I get `()`. Just change it to match your other menu code. `self.m1.add_cascade(menu=self.appmenu, label="apple")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example code from the tutorial does not work all the way for me (at least on my current OS 10.10).  I wouldn't worry about changing the label manually if you are planning to make this a stand alone app.  If you make this a stand alone app with py2app or cx_freeze, the name of you app you set in your `setup.py` script will show in the menubar as `YourAppName`; and the same goes for the `about YourAppName`.

There is a partial solution; reorder your code.  If you move the section that creates the `About this app` object just after the menu is created, it will work.  Here is how it would look in your code:

```
class Main(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title("PyText")
        #Text editor menu items
        self.m1=Menu(self)

        self.appmenu = Menu(self.m1, name="apple")
        self.m1.add_cascade(menu=self.appmenu)
        self.appmenu.add_command(label="About PyText")
        self.appmenu.add_separator()

        # Other menu bar code...
```

Unfortunately, this does not change the name of the main menubar item.  But if you make this an app as I decried above, you don't need to worry about this.

***EDIT***

I found a potential solution that may help you change the the default `Python` menu item to whatever you want.  Go to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30009909/change-title-of-tkinter-application-in-os-x-menu-bar) I found.