# Change title of tkinter app in Mac OSX new versions

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

I have been using the answer provided here and that works just fine under Python 3.7 using pyobjc 6.1

[Change title of Tkinter application in OS X Menu Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30009909/change-title-of-tkinter-application-in-os-x-menu-bar)

However I am starting a new project and am using Python 3.8 and the latest pyobjc 8.1 and even though pyobjc is installed and I can see it in the path I get the error

```
from Foundation import NSBundle
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Foundation'
```

I'm at a loss now as to how to get it working again.

Comment: The [documentation](https://pyobjc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py-modindex.html) for the latest version shows what modules are available. It looks like `Foundations` is now `PyObjCTools.FndCategories`.

Comment: Tried this
from PyObjCTools.FndCategories import NSBundle
Got error in the module 
```File "/Users/eugeniemmcguire/PycharmProjects/AnimalTrakkerSystem/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyObjCTools/FndCategories.py", line 6, in <module>
    from Foundation import NSAffineTransform
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Foundation'```

Comment: I don't use it myself, but from other questions I've seen here, you have to do something special to make PyCharm aware of third-part modules you have installed or are installing. Check the documentation.

Comment: Yep there are some hoops to navigate but according to the latest PyCharm docs I already did that correctly.<sigh>

Comment: You should try your code outside of PyCharm and see if it's the problem.

Comment: Does not work outside of PyCharm either