# Why title does not change in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
import win32api
from tkinter import filedialog
from mood import Dominant
from form import Assessment
import json
ca=Assessment()
window=Toplevel()
window.withdraw()
window.title("Analysis")
```

When I try to change title on the window still the title appears as "tk". I saw some answers but they were related OOP in the main window I could not change the title.

Comment: You remove the window then change its title.  How do you know it hasn't changed?

Comment: At first, I had two windows then removed the second one by menas of withdraw() function then put the .title() after as you see but  still window title is "tk" of course after I run the code :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395431/using-tkinter-in-python-to-edit-the-title-bar See if that helps.

Comment: I run additional two windows on the main window which open with  buttons  in tkinter. I do not know whether it effect or not the main window's title.

Comment: You are hiding the window, so how do you know the title has not changed

Comment: Still it has not changed yet.  Is it related with Toplevel? but I have tried the option already that is window.winfo_toplevel().title("Analysis")

Comment: You are right @Cool Cloud but The window appears blank but the tk titled runs properly. So I do know why tk titled works and my desired window does not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You changed the title of the hidden `Toplevel()` (since you have executed `window.withdraw()`), not the visible root window (created implicitly).

Use `window.master.title("Analysis")` to change the title of the visible root window.

Or create the root window explicitly and change its title as below:

```py
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
window=tk.Toplevel()
window.withdraw()
root.title("Analysis")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: "You changed the title of the hidden Toplevel() (since you have executed window.withdraw()), not the visible root window (created implicitly)." That was the part I did have no clue why it was happening. Thank you :)